# Performance when updating UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibezierpath, cgpath

I'm working on a Mind Mapping app that lets users structure their ideas. When the user adds an idea it is displayed into a `UIScrollView` in the form of a colored bubble. Except for the main bubble, each and every other bubble is linked with an `UIBezierPath` by the bubble that it derives from, just like [here](http://i59.tinypic.com/5yzp50.png).

The user can move the bubbles by dragging them so the `UIBezierPaths` (the links between bubbles) also have to be updated. The problem is that if I stroke a new path every time a bubble moves I get bad performance.

Is there a better way to update the `UIBezierPaths`, so you don't get performance issues? Or should I consider switching to OpenGL?

My drawing code:

```
-(void)setPaths:(UIBezierPath *)paths
{
    _paths = paths;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
   for (UIBezierPath *path in self.paths) {
        [path stroke];
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a thought: What about using a CAShapeLayer and animating its path?

Comment: Have you profiled your code to verify that it is indeed the `UIBezierPaths` that's causing the slowdown? If so, show your drawing code. If not, profile first before assuming that's the issue.

Comment: @user1118321 I did profile my app and the bad performance comes indeed from drawing the `UIBezierPaths`. I posted my drawing code: when the `paths` array is updated, I redraw every path that it contains.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you for the suggestion, I'll think about using a `CAShapeLayer`

Comment: @MartinR I implemented drawing using `CAShapeLayer`. The performance is improved a bit, but it still doesn't keep up with the user dragging the bubbles.